# "How to" construction in German

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, phrase-request

In English, there is the construction *how to + [infinitive],* e.g. in:

> I don't know how to do such and such thing.
>
> How to this and that is a different matter.
>
> How to win friends and influence people.

Is there some equivalent in German? Is *wie zu* valid?

Comment: Can you provide an intended a meaning for the second example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays the German language makes heavy use of the English "How to". There is not a 1:1 equivalent using "wie", but possible alternatives are:

> Wie man xyz macht (How one does xyz)
>   Wie man Pizza zubereitet (How one cooks pizza)
>   Wie man richtig eine Krawatte bindet (How one correctly ties a tie)

I.e. a 3rd person variant ("how one/ how you").

Other possibilities:

> Anleitung zum Kochen
>   Anleitung zum Krawattebinden

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent of this English construction, so you will have to add a subject. E.g.

> Ich weiß nicht, wie man das macht.

or, more personally,

> Ich weiß nicht, wie ich das machen soll.

Answer (score 0):

There's a famous series of DIY books (or "How-Tos") in Germany published since 1962 as as repair manuals for all sorts of cars titled

> Jetzt helfe ich mir selbst: VW Käfer [e.g.]

which basically translates into "How to repair a Volkswagen Beetle".

The GDR hat a similar set of books called "Wie helfe ich mir selbst" on the famous Trabant.

If you want to refer to something comparable, using this title would be sufficient.